# Find $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Can you please verify if my solution is correct.
let $(a_n=\frac{1}{n})$ be a sequence of real numbers. show that $\sup(a_n)=1$ and $\inf(a_n)=0$.

since
 $$n+1>n$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}$$
$$a_{n+1}<a_n$$
therefore, $(a_n)$ is a decreasing function
hence, $\sup(a_n)=a_1=1$
and $\inf(a_n)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

I already have proved the limit to be $0$.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: For what is written, I see you saying that if a sequence is decreasing, then the inf is 0. What am I missing?

Comment: actually I didnt show my proof that lim =0. I just used it here. I should have stated that by the proposition of monotone bounded sequence convergence, the $inf(a_n) = \lim a_n$

Answer (score 4):

To show that $\inf_n (\frac{1}{n}) = 0$ you need to show two things:

i) $0$ is a lower bound.  This is easy since $\frac{1}{n} > 0$ for all $n$.

ii) $0$ is the greatest lower bound.  So suppose there exists $\beta$ a lower bound of $\frac{1}{n}$.  Assume, by way of contradiction, that $\beta > 0$.  Now there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \beta$, contradicting the fact that $\beta$ is a lower bound.